# What's the symbol for a triangle pointing to the right (WHITE RIGHT-POINTING POINTER ▻)?

Tags: symbols, mathjax, pointer

I am looking for a MathJax equivalent of the Unicode symbol called *WHITE RIGHT-POINTING POINTER*:

> ▻

It is a little bit longer than `\triangleright`, which looks like this:

> [image: A screenshot of <code>\triangleright</code>]

Also, I wasn't able to find it using http://detexify.kirelabs.org/.

---

Thanks to marmot I was able to find the LaTeX equivalent: it is called `\whitepointerright`. It does not work in MathJax, though.

Comment: Did you look at  [the comprehensive catalogue](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)?

Comment: @marmot No. I'm looking at it right now.

Comment: @marmot I think I found it. It's probably `\whitepointerright`.

Comment: @marmot However, it doesn't render in MathJax. I'll try to find a solution to this.

Comment: Also check fontawesome.  It has been updated more recently than the catalogue.

Comment: The Unicode symbol can be used, direct as `▻` or as entity `&x25bb;` in HTML/MathJax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MathJax is generally considered off-topic here, but you can use `\rhd` in LaTeX or in MathJax to get something close to `\whitepointerright`. The following image is taken from Safari using MathJax:

[image]

The code renders on Chrome, Firefox, Safari:

```
\[
A\triangleright B\rhd C
\]
```

with `<head>` code:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

and also works in LaTeX using the `amsfonts` package:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that MathJax is offtopic here. I ended up simply using the Unicode symbol.

Answer (score 4):

I used these commands. You don't need document commands to use these commands:

```
A\triangle B\\
A\blacktriangle B\\
A\triangledown B\\
A\blacktriangledown B\\
A\triangleleft B\\
A\blacktriangleleft B\\
A\triangleright B\\
A\blacktriangleright B
```

[image: triangles in action]

Answer (score 3):

The glyph you're looking for seems to be U+25BB WHITE RIGHT-POINTING POINTER which is available in the STIX fonts as `\whitepointerright`.

The easiest way is to import it as a “text symbol”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stixscr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixscr}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.1] stix-mathscr}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pointright}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\usefont{U}{stixscr}{m}{n}\symbol{"D2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\pointright B$

\end{document}
```

The `1.1` magnification factor is used just by way of example. Experiment until finding the right size.

[image]

With `pict2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e,xfp}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pointright}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\point@right\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\point@right}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\point@@right{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\point@@right}[1]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\triangleright$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\ht\z@}%
  \setlength{\dimen@}{\wd\z@}%
  \linethickness{%
    \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.09\unitlength
    \else\ifx#1\textstyle 0.09\unitlength
    \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle 0.11\unitlength
    \else 0.13\unitlength\fi\fi\fi
  }%
  \edef\point@wd{\fpeval{2*(\dimen@/\unitlength)}}%
  \begin{picture}(\point@wd,1)
  \roundjoin
  \polyline(0,0.5)(0,0)(\point@wd,0.5)(0,1)(0,0.2)
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\pointright B \triangleright C$

$\pointright\triangleright$

$\scriptstyle\pointright\triangleright$

$\scriptscriptstyle\pointright\triangleright$

\end{document}
```

[image]