# What is the symbol for a closed (filled in) triangle pointing to the right?

Tags: symbols

I wish to use such a symbol in an `itemize` environment.

I found these symbols: `\triangleright` and `\rhd` from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405519/whats-the-symbol-for-a-triangle-pointing-to-the-right).  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=$\triangleright$]
  \item A
  \item B
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label=$\rhd$]
  \item A
  \item B
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Can you please help me find closed analogues of the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\(\blacktriangleright\)]
    \item A
    \item B
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Should I put it in math mode?

Comment: Also, where did you find it?  Did you find it in that collection of 15,000 symbols?

Comment: It is one of the AMS symbols.

Comment: @Andrew Yes you should put it in math mode, otherwise you will get an error. In my answer it is in math mode since it is between `\(` and `\)`. In this case I must say I simply remembered the command, but in general to find standard symbols you can try [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).